# Use Gram matrix to prove CBS inequality

Tags: matrices, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Hi I am trying to prove the CBS inequality i.e. $|\langle x,y\rangle |\le||x||\,||y||$ by using Gram matrix.

Now I know how to prove Gram matrix $G_w$ is positive semidefinite i.e.
for $z=(z_1,z_2,....,,z_n)^T\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $w=\{w_1,w_2,...,w_n\}\subset X$ then the Gram matrix is positive semidefinite by showing that $$z^*G_w\,z\ge 0$$ where $G_w=\Bigg(\langle w_i,w_j\rangle\Bigg)_{1\le i,j\le n}$

But I am stuck with how to prove CBS inequality using the positive semi definiteness of Gram matrix. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Gram matrix is positive semidefinite, so its every $2\times2$ principal submatrix is positive semidefinite and has nonnegative determinant, i.e. $g_{ii}g_{jj}\ge g_{ij}^2$. Write each entry of $G_w$ as an inner product of vectors among $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ and take square roots on both sides, you recover the CBS inequality.